# Converting SQL query to linq equivalent

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to execute a query in my .net enviroment,

so I'm converting it to the linq equivalent this is the SQL query

```
SELECT
  INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_ressource.ressourec_text1,
  INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_temps.annee_saisie,
  INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_temps.mois_saisi,
  INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_temps.semaine_saisie,
  INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_temps.jour_saisi,
  INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_engagement.engagement_nom,
  INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_projet.projet_nom,
  INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_tache.tache_nom,
  (sum(INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_temps.nbre_jour))/8
FROM
  INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_ressource INNER JOIN INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_temps ON (INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_temps.ressource_id=INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_ressource.ressource_id)
   INNER JOIN INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_tache ON (INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_temps.tache_id=INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_tache.tache_id)
   INNER JOIN INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_projet ON (INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_projet.projet_id=INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_tache.projet_id)
   INNER JOIN INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_engagement ON (INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_projet.engagement_id=INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_engagement.engagement_id)

WHERE
  ( 
  INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_tache.tache_nom  NOT IN  ('Control for Complement day or week', 'Holidays (for internal only)', 'Miscellaneous absences (for internal only)', 'Part time (for internal only)', 'Sick time and job injuries (for internal only)')
  AND  INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_ressource.ressourec_text1  =  'EDCL'
  AND  INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_temps.jour_saisi  >= '2016-03-01'
  AND  INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_temps.jour_saisi  < '2016-04-01'
  )
GROUP BY
  INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_ressource.ressourec_text1, 
  INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_temps.annee_saisie, 
  INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_temps.mois_saisi, 
  INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_temps.semaine_saisie, 
  INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_temps.jour_saisi, 
  INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_engagement.engagement_nom, 
  INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_projet.projet_nom, 
  INFOCENTRE.dbo.issi_tache.tache_nom
```

and converted I have the following so far:

```
from ressource in context.issi_ressource
join temps in context.issi_temps on ressource.ressource_id equals temps.ressource_id
join tache in context.issi_tache on temps.tache_id equals tache.tache_id
join projet in context.issi_projet on tache.projet_id equals projet.projet_id
join engagement in context.issi_engagement on projet.engagement_id equals engagement.engagement_id

where
    ressource.ressourec_text1 == "EDCK" &&
    temps.jour_saisi <= new DateTime(2016, 03, 01) &&
    temps.jour_saisi < new DateTime(2016, 04, 01) &&
    tache.tache_nom != "Control for Complement day or week" &&
    tache.tache_nom != "Holidays (for internal only)" &&
    tache.tache_nom != "Miscellaneous absences (for internal only)" &&
    tache.tache_nom != "Part time (for internal only)" &&
    tache.tache_nom != "Sick time and job injuries (for internal only)" 

group ressource by new {
    ressource.ressourec_text1,
    temps.annee_saisie,
    temps.mois_saisi,
    temps.semaine_saisie,
    temps.jour_saisi,
    engagement.engagement_nom,
    projet.projet_nom,
    tache.tache_nom
} into res

select res;
```

but now I'm trying to get the `nbre_jour` sum devided by 8, does anyone have any clues on how to do this?

Comment: You really should attempt to use the navigation properties instead of joins when you switch over to Linq https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/

Comment: it's not my database, and no FK are made, so I have to do it this way :/

Answer (score 0):

First you really want to group the `nbre_jour` by those values so you can do the sum.

```
group temps.nbre_jour by ...
```

Then your select would just be

```
select new
{
    res.Key.ressourec_text1,
    res.Key.annee_saisie,
    ...
    GiveThisAName = res.Sum()/8
}
```

Just think of Linq's group by like this

> group <things you want to aggregate> by <columns you want to group by>

In the case where there is more than one column to aggregate on it would require a lambda in the aggregate function like this

```
group  new { col1, col2 } by ... into grp
select new 
{ 
    grp.Key, 
    Col1Sum = grp.Sum(x => x.col1), 
    Col2Avg = grp.Average(x => x.col2) 
}
```